# Postback on click is not reliable for collapisble panels

Tags: asp.net, panel

In my page I have a lot of Collapsible Panels with update panels which I use to load different types of information.

These panels are updated by the actions of the user.  Initially I load the customer's information by registration when the user posts back by clicking on a header of a collapsible panel.

My problem is that this isn't reliable.  Users report clicking on the header and that it works sometimes, but sometimes it doesn't post back.

What could be the problem?

Comment: Could you perhaps show the code that doesn't do what you expect/want?

Comment: unable to put my code. first i need the answer for this below question
-> when i using the collapsible panels in asp.net, users click the header panel sometimes its hitting server side and sometimes not ? why ? plz tel me

Comment: Perhaps they are not pressing the correct part of the header, the part that needs to be pressed is not always the whole header. But I can't tell for sure unless there is some code to clarify what you're doing.